# Adding resource server to a AWS Cognito user pool gives error

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have a user pool which is fully working and want to add a resource server.
Whatever identifier or name I try I always get "The identity provider name or identifier is missing."

Does anyone know what can be wrong?

Answer (score 6):

We ran into something a similar error like this. It seems that if ANY scope description is empty or whitespace it throws that error. If you give those scopes a description it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue still exists.
Tried adding a resource server but it throws an error saying "The identity provider name or identifier is missing." However after filling out all the details in the text boxes provided the error was gone and the resource created successfully.

Comment: Yes that is what @BobanL said